# Display YUV/RGBA data native code in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, port

I have a decoder ported to iOS. The decoder is written in normal C language. In android we have some API through which we can render the decoded frames(will be in YUV, if required can be converted to RGBA).

Is there a similar functionality in iOS in which we can render the decoded data from the C code itself(not from the objective c part of the code).

I tried googling but found ways to render data only from the objective side of the code and did'nt find a way to do it from the native side of the code.

Please suggest a way to do so. A link to some similar example will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decoded data means a RAW data that needs to be displayed. RAW data can be YUV or RGB...

Comment: I'm just wondering: Which API on Android can render YUV frames natively (w/o converting to rgba)? What you could do under iOS is: using OpenGL ES 2.0 for rendering and do the 'conversion' inside the shader. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428108/ios-how-to-draw-a-yuv-image-using-opengl